# How to use custom font in website

Tags: html, css, drupal-7, web

I use this code in style.css file and can add my custom font where I want.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: Titr;
    src: url('fonts/L4i_Titr.ttf');
    url('Thonburi-Bold.eot');
}
```

But this work for localhost. When I put my local website in the web, font don't work.
What's problem?
What's the solution?

Comment: make sure you have uploaded the font on server.

Comment: I'm sure I've uploaded in server.

Comment: check the file path in your question. One of them haven't a correct file path..

Comment: my font is in this path. "site.com/site/all/themes/theme/fonts/L4i_Titr.ttf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Sure fonts are uploaded on server and in your question path is wrong for `.eot format`. Since All latest browser support the `.woff` font format type. So you can use `.ttf` and `.woff` font format type.

**Thats work on your local machine because of fonts are available on your system**. After uploading the font on server and given a correct file path in CSS file your custom fonts will appear.

As well make sure you define the `font MIME Type` for all fonts type you are using.  For  example `.woff` format set  a MIME type in server like **application/x-font-woff** .

Using [**@font-face Generator**](http://www.font-face-generator.com/) you can convert font format from `.ttf` to `.eot, .svg, .woff`.

**Update:**

On `.htaccess` file add font the following types:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titr';
  src: url('fonts/L4i_Titr.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('fonts/L4i_Titr.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

Comment: just made a one line bold, so you can see why on your local its working?

Comment: I can't understand, explain.

Comment: okay for example you download a Arabian font and installed on your local machine, so it will only your machine not any other machines. same thing apply when you used a custom font; that will work on your local because that font file is on your `c:\\fonts` location. Now to use a custom font work on every machine you have to upload the font file on the server and then in CSS give a correct file path.. As simple as .

Comment: also make sure you defined the font MIME Type as well on your server setting; As I alredy mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I gave relative path to font!

Comment: I dont understand MIME what's. I'm seraching about it

Comment: are you using Apache Server or IIS server?

Comment: I'm using both local and server Apache.

Comment: I've updated my answer please  check. just copy the lines and paste in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: for IE works correctly.. firefox vs is 29. for local works firefox but for web don't work

Comment: it will work, have you add the  type on your `.htaccess` file and upload that file?

Answer (score 0):

If Kheema Pandey's solution dosen't work then maybe there is something wrong with the font file. And if this is true then the only reson because of which the font is working on localhost is because you already have it installed on your system. So just check the font file for any errors.

**EDIT :**
Have you tried opening the online page in multiple browsers. If not then try it beacuse it might be possible that a specific browser might not support a font**(happened with me)**.

Comment: if the local font format is .ttf and in the server is .TTF, I changed it to .ttf. But not work